# Why my .zip file is downloaded empty?

Tags: php, html, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to start a download of a zip through my server.

This type of zip file contains a number of pdf that are generated.

The problem is that the bags and dump it but mark me open this damaged or there is an error and when I extract tells me is empty.

Here I do the whole procedure?

Code of descargar.php

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$filename = 'walkingdead.zip';


if($zip->open($filename,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===true) {
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath('../walkingdead');


$zip->open('walking.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

 //Sin notificaciones, y que el server no comprima
@ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
  //Encabezados para archivos .zip
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
  //El nombre predeterminado que verá el cliente
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
  //Que no haya límite en la ejecución del script
@set_time_limit(0);

  //Imprime el contenido del archivo
readfile($filename);


// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Basic debugging: `readfile($files);` what exactly do you think readfile() will do when you pass in your directoryiterator object?

Comment: I want my .zip file is downloaded to my pc user

Comment: Then why are you feeding an object to a function that expects a filename?

Comment: i am soryy, the code is modified by this

$filename="walkingdead.zip";   -----  readfile($filename); ----- but the problem does not go away

Comment: you don't close your zip until AFTER you've done readfile(). I don't know when ziparchive actually starts writing bytes to disk, but you shouldn't be keeping it open while reading it from it anyways.

Comment: Plus you are calling $zip->open twice, with different file names - what's the point of that?

Answer (score 0):

Move `$zip->close();` to before `readfile($filename)`.